# Unable to access WP admin

Tags: htaccess, shared-hosting, wp-filesystem, virus

I cannot access admin via:

```
http://example.com/admin
```

or

```
http://example.com/wp-admin
```

> ```
> Fatal error: Class 'ObjectModel' not found in /home3/xxxxxx/public_html/example.com/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php on line 28
> ```

I have had a trojan on my website that will put own `.htaccess` redirect stuff. And what is worse the WordPress version was up to date 3.5.1 and I have almost no plugins installed.

File permissions were `644` and directories `755`. How can it write to `.htaccess`?

What file permission should I set for `.htaccess`?

I am on a shared Justhost hosting.

Comment: Download the latest version of WordPress from http://wordpress.org/download and override all of the present core files via FTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear you don't need to worry about much - if its a fresh installation and you don't have any data on your website - eg post, article, images or anything then I prefer you t install a clean fresh wordpress again from the sketches after a complete scan of your hosting.

and if you have data in your hosting I am sure you can access your data base from cpanel or hosting central of your account download your data base its the most important thing you need becaue wordpress is just a CMS. after downloading data base follow step 1 and load the data base from within wordpress or from hosting center.

the third that is download wordpress and find wp-dependencies.php upload it to appropiate folder might help you keep us up to date what are you doing.