# Unable to access dashboard (wp-admin) only

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I have a site with wp 3.8.1. After I'm logged in to site, white screen welcomes me instead of dashboard page. It logged me in the site, I can access another admin pages & main site but not dashboard. On the other hand, it seems like js/jquery not working in admin pages like "widgets". Here I can't drag or drop widgets.

In the console while I visit admin pages, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined` error. In addition, I've checked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101673/unable-to-access-wp-admin) before I post this issue but not related with that.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all Plugins? If this resolves the issue try re-enabling them one by one to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @kraftner it worked after re-enable plugins but I'm still stuck on error & I worry about the problem happens again next time. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376) You re-enabled _all_ of your plugins?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I did them, too.

Comment: If that comment means "Yes" to my question then one of your plugins has buggy code. Without knowing which one and what the precise error is this isn't going to be answerable, and may be off-topic anyway.